# Kendo grid page index get 0 if no data available

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid for data display. If the data is available then page index starts from 1. If the data is not available i.e Empty result grid index start from 0. Functionally there is no page index 0. 
I need to show page index 1 even for an empty grid.

Comment: Why are you needing this? Kendo grid will always show page index 0 if there is no data in the grid. That's the natural behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text of the page numbers using jquery in the databound event.

```
dataBound: function (e) {
   if (e.sender.dataSource.view().length === 0) {
       $('.k-pager-numbers span.k-state-selected').text('1')
   }
}
```